# YEOMAN INSTALL FAILS

Tags: node.js, yeoman, seeding

Thanks before starting, Am a kinda of a newbie using yeoman for seeding my new project. I tried to install using, this command

```
npm install -g yo
```

i get this error

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: yo
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /root/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: yo
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
```

my node version is, **v0.6.12**,
my npm version is,  **1.1.4**

Help will be mush appreciated.

Comment: You have to update **node.js**.

Comment: how can i do that any links..?

Comment: http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-fundamentals-how-to-upgrade-the-node-js-version/

Comment: `Yo` needs node `>=0.10.0` and npm `>=1.2.10` https://github.com/yeoman/yo/blob/master/package.json#L13:L14

Comment: Recommended to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Got it right Puigcerber. Thank u all guys